# Try to dispatch a Thunk from a Redux store dispatch. Error Argument of type 'MyThunk' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using `Next.js` and I've got a complex admin form page that I need to use a 2nd Redux store. I know this is almost never needed, but I really like the way Redux handles the state updates. In my form, I'll have many actions and some of them are `async`, because some of the fields are image uploads. I don't want to create a slice for that page in my global store (which handles stuff like `auth`, `user` and other global data).

So I'm creating the new `store` it by using the following code:

```
import { configureStore, EnhancedStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { useMemo } from "react";
import adminBlogPostSlice from "./adminBlogPostSlice";

export const useAdminBlogPostStore = () : EnhancedStore => {

  const store = useMemo(() => {
    return configureStore({
      reducer: adminBlogPostSlice,
      devTools: false
    });
  },[]);

  return store;
};
```

So, in my page container I'm doing:

```
const AdminBlogPostContainer: React.FC<AdminBlogPostContainer> = (props) => {

  const { mode } = props;
  const { slug } = useRouter().query;

  const store = useAdminBlogPostStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    const { dispatch } = store;
    dispatch(THUNK.LOAD({mode,slug}));
  },[mode,store,slug]);

  return(
    <Provider store={store}>    // PROVIDING THE STORE TO THE REST OF THE PAGE
      <AdminBlogPostPage/>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

But I'm getting error on the `Thunk` dispatch call.

[image]

This is my `Thunk` type. I mean, `THUNK.LOAD` (the one that is being dispatched) is of type `AdminBlogPostThunk`

```
type AdminBlogPostThunk = ThunkAction<
  Promise<void> | void,
  AdminBlogPostState,
  unknown,
  AnyAction
>
```

It seems to work fine one level below by using the `useDispatch` hook. I'm not able to use this hook on `AdminBlogPostContainer` because that's where the `Provider` is being added.

I saw this page in the official docs: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to use the store the way I'm trying to? Any other ideas?

Comment: Are U sure that your action contains `type` property? Because it should - according to convention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare the hook as returning `EnhancedStore`. Let TS infer the return type.  That way TS should figure out that "it's a Redux store, but with the thunk middleware actually included".

Comment: Thank you so much, Mark. It works. I know that it's not that common to use multiple stores inside an app. Do you see any problems the way I'm implementing it? I tried handling the form with `react-final-form` but the `async` updates (image uploads) make it so much more complicated. I really don't want to mix page state with my global state (that is being hydrated by Next.js). `RTK` handles it so clearly and elegantly that it's by far the best approach I could find to handle this complex form that I've built. Thanks again.